# SharePoint listview color change on checkbox click

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint list and I have changed the row color by adding this piece of code in CEWP.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-alternating
{
background-color: White;
}
</style>
```

Now when I click on the checkbox at the left of the row, the item color is very dark and the letters are not viewable.

Is there any way to change the color of them too?

Answer (score 1):

Add more [CSS selectors](http://www.webteacher.ws/2011/12/07/css-selectors-101/), the Table Rows you click get the class *s4-itm-selected*

```
.s4-itm-selected td {
  color: blue;
}
```

You need to add extra CSS selectors to restyle the Title link because the A tag has its own styling